# export SAS data set into SAS file (sas7bdat) in SAS Enterprise Guide 5.1

Tags: database, sas

```
EXPORT PROC 
OUTFILE="C:users\den\Desktop\export_project. sas7bdat" REPLACE;

RUN;
```

I'm trying to run this code in Programs to generate SAS files but It gives me an error.

I have multiple temporary data sets (ex. Task, User, Errors, etc) stored in the libraries in work folder. How do I export these data sets into sas7bdat?

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to "export" a SAS dataset to another SAS dataset.  Just copy them.  For example you could create a libref that points to the folder you want to write them into and then use PROC COPY to copy them.

```
libname out 'C:\users\den\Desktop\' ;
proc copy inlib=work outlib=out ;
  select export_project;
run;
```

Comment: does 'select' statement select the folder that dataset is in (such as work folder)? or the name of dataset (ex. Task)?

Comment: The SELECT statement is optional and can be used to limit the MEMBERs (i.e. datasets) in the source library that are copied. The INLIB= is the source library and the OUTLIB= is the target library.